# Insert data in database in Drupal

Tags: php, sql, drupal

I want to insert a result in mysql, i use this query:

```
$sql= "INSERT into {test} WHERE Id = $currentID (soortstage)VALUES('%s')";
```

that is the error:

```
* user warning:

You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the
right syntax to use near  `WHERE Id =
(Soortstage)VALUES('132')'` at line 1
query: `INSERT into test WHERE  Id =
(Soortstage)VALUES('132') in
C:\xampp\htdocs\testplanning\modules\planning\planning.module on line 425.`

* warning: 

Invalid argument supplied for
foreach() in
`C:\xampp\htdocs\testplanning\includes\form.inc
on line 1213.`
```

Have someone a idea? Thanks!

Comment: what's the value of `$currentID`? Seems to be null.

Comment: `INSERT INTO WHERE`? Do you want an UPDATE or an INSERT?

Comment: I want to insert values in a created row. the $currentID is the row that I will insert a value to. In these row there are some fields empty and I will just insert 1 value.

Comment: So you want to UPDATE the row, maybe you should learn the basics of SQL first, you won't regret doing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html), which will either UPDATE or INSERT based on whether or not the primary ID of the record exists.

`REPLACE INTO {test} WHERE Id = $currentID (soortstage) VALUES('%s')`

But, frankly, you mention Drupal, which has a nice helper for this: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/6

Comment: More importantly, this query should use proper placeholders for $currentID (aka %d), this is not safe. Also, REPLACE is MySQL specific. To be compatible with PostgreSQL, you need to something like http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/6

Comment: Indeed: When @Yannick wants to make a proper, re-usable Drupal-module, the query should be generic and not MySQL-specific. But since he stated he uses MySQL, I thought that to be less important :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an update query

```
$sql= "UPDATE {test} SET soortstage = '%s' WHERE Id = $currentID ";
```

Comment: almost good solution, but it gives this error:     * user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 query: UPDATE test SET Soortstage = '162' WHERE Id = in C:\xampp\htdocs\testplanning\modules\planning\planning.module on line 426.
    * warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\testplanning\includes\form.inc on line 1213.

Comment: it is because `$currentID` does not have any value